# Postfix aborts installation after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, postfix, sendmail

I cannot install Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04 after upgrading from 16.04 and previously using sendmail.  The output below occurs while attempting to install *Postfix* using `apt`:

```
Job for postfix.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postfix.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript postfix, action "restart" failed.
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-24 04:56:39 PST; 6ms ago
    Process: 1034683 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 24 04:56:38 Hoth systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Dec 24 04:56:38 Hoth postfix/postfix-script[1034691]: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running
Dec 24 04:56:39 Hoth systemd[1]: postfix.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 24 04:56:39 Hoth systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 24 04:56:39 Hoth systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

The key seems to be: **fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running**

I have tried:

- Reinstall
- Purging `postfix`
- Disabling the `sendmail` systemd unit
- Purging `sendmail`
- Manually stopping postfix prior to reinstall

It seems that the installation starts Postfix and then tries to start it again and then chokes due to this unexpected state.